# How to create User specific Session in Worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an android application using Worklight 6.1. I am using SingleStepAuthentication process. Now with single userId multiple user can login to the app, but i dont want this. I would like to know how can i check the user is currently active. and also if i am login with different user, i am getting the following error.
 Illegal State: Cannot change identity of an already logged in user in realm 'SingleStepAuthRealm' The application must logout first.

here is the below adapter procedure. Please have a look.

```
function getUserLoginDetails(username, password){   
        var input = {
                method : 'get',
                returnedContentType : 'json',
                path : 'webrootPath',

                'parameters' : {
                    'userId' : username,
                        'password' :password

                    },

            };
        var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

        var userIdentity = {
                userId: username,
                displayName: password,
                attributes: {
                    data: response
                }
        };      
        WL.Server.setActiveUser("SingleStepAuthRealm", userIdentity);   
        return response,userIdentity;                   

}
```

In authentication configuration.xml below code

```
</customSecurityTest>           
    <customSecurityTest name="SingleStepAuthAdapter-securityTest">
        <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SingleStepAuthRealm"/>
    </customSecurityTest>

    <realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="SingleStepAuthRealm">
        <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-function" value="SingleStepAuthAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
        <parameter name="logout-function" value="SingleStepAuthAdapter.onLogout"/>
    </realm>
```

Please suggest.

Regards,

Saroj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to first "reset" the active user before setting it again, as you cannot "replace" it.

First call `WL.Server.setActiveUser("myRealm", null)` and then call `WL.Server.setActiveUser("myRealm", {...})`.

Comment: HI Idan, thank you for your reply. I would like to avoid multiple users login with single Id. How to do this. please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that will allow you to detect users that are already logged in. You need to either have this functionality on your backend or implement in manually, e.g. by creating a database and keeping the track of logins/logouts.